# Store data from a dynamic form in an arrayfield (postgrsql)

Tags: python, django

New in python/django development, i'm stopped by a problem.
I have a model 'Order' who stores ... orders

```
class Order(models.Model):
    datecom = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de commande")
    when = models.ForeignKey(OrdTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    stand = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    products = JSONField(default=defaultlist)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dateliv = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date de livraison", blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "- Commande"
        verbose_name_plural = "- Commandes"
        ordering = ['dateliv']

    def get_products(self):
        return format_html_join('', '{} : {} <br>', ([(product, score) for score, product in self.products]))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

As you can see, 'product' is an ArrayField (Postgresql) who stores a list of product, with, for each one, a quantity.
Like this:

```
def defaultlist():
    return [
        (15, "Product 1"),
        (1, "Product 2"),
        (2, "Product 3")
    ]
```

I am creating a public (but user authenticated) form who can store data to ordering products.
This form have to store order date, name of the 'stand' etc. and (this my problem) store product name and quantity for each product.
Only products with quantity > 0 have to be stored.
It's a mess for me.
How can I display input field for each row product/quantity in a model form and format this inputs to store in the arrayfield ?

Any idea to do this ?